# Admob - Set the App Settings - Test Mode to 'Disable' on Release?

Tags: admob

I just wrote and released to the market my first 'ad-supported' android app. I see ads served on the emulator and my device but Im earning a few cents a day with close to 1000 downloads (700 active) in the released world. I have been investigating how to increase revenue from the app (just pennies right now) by going into the Admob App Settings for my App.  I see a setting there for 'Disable Test Mode for all Requests' - should I enable that? Its currently set to 'Use test mode setting set in client code'. Have I been serving customers the 'Test' ads only? The Admob is very vague on the topic.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

Feel free to change that option, but that shouldn't make a difference; the Google AdMob SDK prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Your app can call `adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR)` to get test ads on emulators, and `adRequest.addTestDevice("YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_FROM_ADMOB_LOGS")` to get test ads on your specific device.  But even if you released with that code, all devices that are not yours, or are not emulators, will get network ads.

Comment: Thanks much - Its just strange that since clciking that option (to disable) my revenue has increased 30%.

Comment: revenue is generated off of clicks, not impressions.  You may just have a higher CTR today.  A better comparison would be how many impressions you served today vs. yesterday